# Summa C program crashing

Tags: c, loops, crash-reports

Excuse me if this tread has already been published before, I have few time for getting this code right because I need to send it tomorrow to my programming teacher but I'm not able to see what's wrong. It's simply a summa code with a limit number...but it keeps wrong. I tried to write the same instructions in C++ and it somehow works. Why!?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main()
{
    int a, n, suma;

    suma = 0;

    printf("Introduce un numero límite \n");

    scanf("%d", n);        

    for(a=0; a <= n; a++)
    {
        suma=suma+a;
    }

    printf("La suma de todos los numeros es: %d", suma);
}
```

Ignore the prints...they are just interacting with the user: "where should I stop adding numbers? The sum is...". Things alike.

I would be very thankful to you if you could help me. I'm at first year and a I am a newbie in C...

Oh! All the compiling warnings: http://puu.sh/54Rnh.png

Comment: As a note to your warning picture. The asterisk, `*`, denotes that it expects a pointer (address). So, when you get a similar warning later that should be a clue. If you do not have it. This is a good read [K&R C](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0131103628/?tag=stackoverfl08-20) , and stackowerflow has a good list of resources [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the address of `n` in scanf

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

Just as a side note, you don't need to start your loop from `0` to calculate the sum

```
for(a=1; a <= n; ++a) //start from 1
```

Doesn't do much but saves one iteration.

Also, use preincrement when you do not intend to use the result of the expression as it has a slightly lesser overhead than postincrement.

Answer (score 0):

The [`scanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) function requires the address of the respective variables (`n`) declared in the string format `"%d"`. Change your code to:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

and everything will be OK and your teacher will give you a good note

Answer (score 0):

**[scanf()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/scanf.html)** reads in from the standard input stream. To store what has been read, you need to provide a proper address. Pointers hold the address.

`&` is unary operator helps you get the address of the operand.

`&n` is a valid pointer expression, provides you the address of `n`, wherein you will want to store the value for `n`

So, turn your `scanf()` to

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```